# Multiple hosts with the same DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

In C#.NET Core you can create a generic host using the following code:

```
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, collection) => {
        collection.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
        collection.AddHostedService<MyService>();
    });
await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
```

This creates a new instance of `MyService` with the default DI container.

Now, say that I want to create a new host inside `MyService`. This is easy enough (a web host in this case):

```
IWebHost webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
    .Build();
    .RunAsync();
```

This webhost will have its own Dependency Injection container, so it will *not* have access to all dependencies I've already added to the generic host container: i.e. it will not be able to have `IMyClass` injected into `MyStartup`.

I've also tried adding a custom `IServiceProviderFactory<>` using the following code (based on the `.UseDefaultServiceProvider()` code where they use `IServiceCollection` as the builder type):

```
public class CustomServiceProviderFactory :  IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public CustomServiceProviderFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public IServiceCollection CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services;
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
    {
        return _provider;
    }
}
```

Then in my `HostBuilder` I added it through `.UseServiceProviderFactory(new CustomServiceProviderFactory(_serviceProvider))`, but for some reason the `HostedService` is instantiated before this is created, causing DI exceptions about not finding the required objects.

However, seeing as `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is now the preferred way to create a webhost ([in .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0)), and an `IWebHostBuilder` does *not* have an option to set a custom `IServiceProviderFactory` this does seem like a dead end.

How can I have the webhost use the same DI container as the initial generic host?

Comment: Is the goal to truly share a container and/or the services in it? Could you not have container configuring logic in a central place and then configure containers similarly by calling this logic? I realize I could be wrong if you need a shared singleton or something stateful. Perhaps you could add to your question and clarify. What you're trying to do sounds interesting but might be overreaching Core's capabilities. Just a thought.

Comment: @Kit I do indeed need shared singletons and stateful dependencies :)

Comment: A possibility may be to switch the default containers on both to something like Autofac, and then add a shared subcontainer to those two containers. So you have different ones still, but a shared child on both.

Comment: I've considered different containers, but I'd really like a native solution.

Comment: @GTHvidsten, were you able to come up with a solution to this?

Comment: I'm interested in this question too, any built in solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do the same thing and this is what I have landed on. Not fully tested but it does appear to work.

First, in my base/first `HostBuilder`, add the service collection as a service so an `IServiceCollection` can be resolved via DI later on.

```cs
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
        services.AddHostedService<MyApp>();
        services.AddSingleton(services);
    });
```

In `IHostedService.StartAsync()` I create the WebHost. I copied the use of `services.Replace` from the functionality inside `UseDefaultServiceProvider()`:

```cs
IWebHost host = WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var options = new ServiceProviderOptions();               
                services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>>(new CustomServiceProviderFactory(_services, options)));
            })
            .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
            .Build();
```

In the constructor of my `CustomServicesProvider`, I also need to remove any `IHostedService` services or else it appears you enter an infinite loop of the service starting. When creating the service provider, I add everything from the constructor-passed service collection to the local service collection.

```cs
class CustomServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _baseServices;
    private readonly ServiceProviderOptions _options;

    public CustomServiceProviderFactory(IServiceCollection baseServices, ServiceProviderOptions options)
    {
        _baseServices = baseServices;
        _options = options;
        _baseServices.RemoveAll<IHostedService>();
    }
    
    public IServiceCollection CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services;
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var service in _baseServices)
        {
            containerBuilder.Add(service);
        }

        return containerBuilder.BuildServiceProvider(_options);
    }
}
```

I was then able to create a `Controller` after adding `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints(...)` in my startup class. Injecting `IMyService` was successfully resolved and I could use it as normal.

You could also test it by just adding `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMyService>()` in your `Startup.Configure()` method and see that the correct service is returned.